# SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet; Snapshot isolation transaction failed in database

Tags: sql-server, hibernate

I am trying to reproduce and fix the recently caught exception:

```
[jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] ? Snapshot isolation transaction failed in database 'config_db' because the object accessed by the statement has been modified by a DDL statement in another concurrent transaction since the start of this transaction.  It is disallowed because the metadata is not versioned. A concurrent update to metadata can lead to inconsistency if mixed with snapshot isolation.
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:280) ~[spring-orm-5.1.20.RELEASE.jar:5.1.20.RELEASE]
[stdout]    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:254) ~[spring-orm-5.1.20.RELEASE.jar:5.1.20.RELEASE]
[stdout]    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:531) ~[spring-orm-5.1.20.RELEASE.jar:5.1.20.RELEASE]
[stdout]    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61) ~[spring-tx-5.1.20.RELEASE.jar:5.1.20.RELEASE]
[stdout]    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242) ~[spring-tx-5.1.20.RELEASE.jar:5.1.20.RELEASE]
[stdout]    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:154) ~[spring-tx-5.1.20.RELEASE.jar:5.1.20.RELEASE]
[stdout]    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:140) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.23.RELEASE.jar:?]
[stdout]    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$ExposeRepositoryInvocationInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:347) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.23.RELEASE.jar:?]
[stdout]    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93) ~[spring-aop-5.1.20.RELEASE.jar:5.1.20.RELEASE]
[stdout]    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.23.RELEASE.jar:?]
[stdout]    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.1.20.RELEASE.jar:5.1.20.RELEASE]
[stdout]    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy280.findById(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
```

The generated query (**note:** I removed the column names intentionally) is run within `read-only` transaction that uses the `readonlyTransactionManager` which routes the query to SQL Server replica node. The used isolation level is `Isolation.DEFAULT`:

```
select *
from config_db.dbo.Program programdmo0_
       left outer join config_db.dbo.SupplementalSection supplement1_ on programdmo0_.Id = supplement1_.ProgramId
       left outer join config_db.dbo.QuestionBlock questionbl2_ on supplement1_.Id = questionbl2_.SectionId
       left outer join config_db_db.dbo.Question questions3_ on questionbl2_.Id = questions3_.QuestionBlockId
       left outer join config_db_db.dbo.QuestionDetails questionde4_ on questions3_.Id = questionde4_.QuestionId
where programdmo0_.Id = ?
```

DBA confirmed that DB isolation level is set to `READ COMMITTED`.

Appreciate if anyone can help me to understand why this exception is thrown if the `SNAPSHOT` isolation level is not enabled?

Comment: Either a DDL trigger doing something weird, or another transaction running at the same time using `SNAPSHOT` and running DDL, is my guess. If you are using Availability Groups the secondaries are always in `SNAPSHOT`

Comment: Adding to what @Charlieface mentioned, all queries on the read-only replica implicitly run in snapshot isolation. The error suggests a DDL operation was performed on the primary, causing the error on the secondary replica.

Comment: @Charlieface, thanks I will check it with DBA and will return.

Comment: @DanGuzman, thanks for you input. How can I verify that my read-only transaction runs with SNAPSHOT isolation level. Also, I was trying to reproduce the issue, I delay my read-only transaction created in application and started a new transaction where I alter table column type, then resume the read-only so it can read the data from the table - unfortunately the exception was not thrown. Though, I noticed the alter changes are not instantly available for replica. Can you recommend how to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Maybe some column names are using reserved keywords? It failing when you select just “id”?

Comment: just another thoughts: are annotations in place? like this one @Transactional..?

Comment: @Andy, the issue is intermittent. Yes the `@Transactional(transactionManager = "readonlyTransactionManager", readOnly = true)` is in place.

Comment: @I.Domshchikov, changes are applied to read-only replicas by redo threads so there may be a delay before changes are available in the secondary even after the changes are hardened in the log. I think you'll need to wait for the redo to complete in your repro.

Comment: @DanGuzman, thanks for the answer. Can you pls confirm that my steps to reproduce the issue are correct. Begin read-only transaction and stop it right before doing the select. Begin another concurrent transaction and change the table column type (for instance from `Program` table) but don't commit transaction. Release the first transaction so it fires select query. Expecting to get an exception, but it is not thrown.

Comment: @I.Domshchikov, the steps to repro are 1) begin tran in secondary and run select (the select will start the read-only transaction), 2) modify table on primary and commit (commit will harden the change on the secondary and the redo will apply the change), 3) run select on secondary. You can also get the error if you run a long-running select query on the secondary and modify/commit the DDL while the query is running as long as redo applies the change before the query completes.

Comment: @DanGuzman, thanks I will try and let you know.

Comment: @DanGuzman, I was able to reproduce the issue with the steps you provided above. Thanks for your support.